# Family Tree numbered list in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, lists

This one has been killing me and I can't seem to find a good solution. I'm making a document for a family tree and am trying to get the numbering right in InDesign.

The numbering goes as follows:

1.0.0.0
1.(is the generation)0.(are the kids from this generation)0.(the kids from this generation)0.(and so forth)

So in this example we have this:

[image]

This is still relatively easy.

[image]

Here is where it already starts to become complex.

[image]

Here it becomes impossible...

Basically for every 'enter' the number goes +1 and it adds a number after the sequence
n+1.0.0.(+1)

Now, how do I replicate this in InDesign? Because I can't seem to find a solution that lets me do what I want.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in InDesign using *Numbering* with several *Levels*.

For each generation you need to have a *Paragraph Style* with a corresponding *Level*.

[image]

In the *Paragraph Style Options* of the first generation we can set up *Bullets and Numbering* like this:

[image]

Note that:

- *Level* is set to *1*.
- *Number* is set to `^#.` . *Current Level* (`^#`), a period (`.`) and a space ( ).
- *Mode* is set to *Continue From Previous Number*.

The second generation will of course have *Level* set to *2* and *Number* can be set to `^1.^#.` . *Level 1* (`^1`), a period (`.`), *Current Level* (`^#`), a period (`.`) and a space ( ).

The ninth generation will have *Level* set to *9* and *Number* set to `^1.^2.^3.^4.^5.^6.^7.^8.^#.` . All previous levels with a period in between followed by the current leve, a period and a space.

InDesign only supports nine levels, so that might become a problem for you. I see you've already reached level 8 in your last example so you can only add one more generation before the method breaks.